# Extract JSON Value After OCR Relative To Other Values?

Tags: json, vb.net

I'm using Azure Computer Vision API to extract text from an image. In this particular use case i'm attempting to extract a bit of text that in the image looks like this "Person ID: ########" where the # is a numeric person number.

Here is a sample of the JSON returned from the API:

```
{"language": "en",
"textAngle": 0.0,
"orientation": "Up",
"regions": [
  {
    "boundingBox": "212,169,1384,359",
    "lines": [
    {
      "boundingBox": "228,169,281,36",
      "words": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "228,169,141,28",
          "text": "Output"
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "386,169,123,36",
          "text": "Report"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "boundingBox": "212,279,287,25",
      "words": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "212,280,116,24",
          "text": "Person"
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "341,279,42,25",
          "text": "ID:"
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "408,279,91,25",
          "text": "15060"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "boundingBox": "279,326,104,25",
      "words": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "279,326,104,25",
          "text": "Notes:"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
  "boundingBox": "2436,172,159,32",
  "lines": [
    {
      "boundingBox": "2436,172,159,32",
      "words": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "2436,172,159,32",
          "text": "Operator:"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "boundingBox": "2627,172,290,216",
  "lines": [
    {
      "boundingBox": "2627,172,103,32",
      "words": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "2627,172,103,32",
          "text": "Output"
        }
      ]
    },
      "boundingBox": "2629,329,288,37",
      "words": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "2683,329,234,37",
          "text": "xm"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "boundingBox": "2875,381,41,7",
      "words": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "2875,381,41,7",
          "text": "LEAR"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
  "boundingBox": "2304,2353,706,32",
  "lines": [
    {
      "boundingBox": "2304,2353,706,32",
      "words": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "2817,2353,193,32",
          "text": "Incorporated."
        }
      ]}]}]}
```

I've trimmed it down quite a bit. You can see that the Person ID: 12345 gets split it up into a section with Person, ID:, 12345.

I need to extract the number from the person ID, but the way i do it currently, if the data output changes, it just won't work:

I'm currently doing something along these lines:

```
Dim _tmp1 = o1("regions")(0)("lines")(1)("words")(1)("text")
Dim _tmp2 = o1("regions")(0)("lines")(1)("words")(2)("text")
```

Then i perform a trivial check to see if _tmp1 = "ID:"

There has got to be a better way to grab the correction value. I thought about just extracting all the "text" keys and then attempt to do a match on Person ID: and grab the data after that until the next space, but then if the extract number contained an extra space it would fail in that method.

There is a method to process items that can not be auto extracted, i'm just trying to improve the chances that the auto extraction will not fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is an easier way. You can use `Newtonsoft.JSON` to quickly and easily serialize JSON data into a class. For example, the following JSON:

Here's a generic example:

First, define the object in terms of what you see in your data

```
public class Account
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Then, take your JSON and call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` on it.

```
string json = @"{
  'Email': 'james@example.com',
  'Active': true,
  'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z',
  'Roles': [
    'User',
    'Admin'
  ]
}";

Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);

Console.WriteLine(account.Email);
// james@example.com
```

You'll end up with an object whose properties are seamlessly filled from the JSON.

I find it's easiest to install with this [NuGet package.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)